# over drawn the circle when input angle in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, geometry

```
    var theTextField:TextField = new TextField();
    var theText:TextField = new TextField();

    theTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    theTextField.border = true;
    theTextField.x = 50;
    theTextField.y = 10;
    theTextField.height = 20;
    theTextField.multiline = true;
    theTextField.wordWrap = true;

    theText.border = false;
    theText.x = 10;
    theText.y = 10;
    theText.text = "Angle";
    addChild(theText);
    addChild(theTextField);


    submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_handler);
    function click_handler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
       var txt:String = theTextField.text;
       ang = Number(txt);

       if (ang<0)
       {
          angle =  -  ang;
       }
       else
       {
          angle = 360 - ang;

        }
       var circleSlider:CircleSlider=new CircleSlider(120,angle); //draw Circle    According to the angle i think here is problem becoz every time clicked it creates new circle and draw over the old circle.


       circleSlider.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
       circleSlider.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
       circleSlider.addEventListener(CircleSliderEvent.CHANGE,  circleSliderEventHandler);
       addChild(circleSlider);
           }
```

Can someone help me.

```
      var circleSlider:CircleSlider=new CircleSlider(120,angle);//draw Circle    According to the angle i think here is problem becoz every time clicked it creates new circle and draw over the old circle.
```

this code is the problem. CircleSlider is a separate class.I tried like this

```
      circleSlider.CircleSlider(120,angle);
```

but it gives an error ""  Call to a possibly undefined method CircleSlider through a reference with static type CircleSlider.""

when i run the program and input value as 90.
[image: 123]

then i enter another value as 180 then it becomes
[image: 1233]

how can i overcome this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your click handler is executed you're creating a new instance of your circle class and adding it to the stage without removing the old instance. I think the best way to resolve it would be to move the logic you have in the constructor of your `CircleSlider` class into a separate public method, say `draw` and call that in the click handler.

Your code would look something like this:

```
// Set up the circle once
var circleSlider = new CircleSlider();
circleSlider.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
circleSlider.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
circleSlider.addEventListener(CircleSliderEvent.CHANGE,  circleSliderEventHandler);

// and add it to the stage once
addChild(circleSlider);

function click_handler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
       var txt:String = theTextField.text;
       ang = Number(txt);

       if (ang<0)
       {
          angle =  -  ang;
       }
       else
       {
          angle = 360 - ang;

      }
        // Now simply redraw in the same circle instance
       circleSlider.draw(120,angle); //draw Circle    According to the angle i think here is problem becoz every time clicked it creates new circle and draw over the old circle.
}
```

Assuming you're using the drawing API to draw the graphic, you could draw the circle (which seems to be constant) in the constructor (once) and the line illustrating the angle in the draw method (repeatedly). You'll need to clear the old line each time like this:

```
// Assumes you're drawing in the graphics property of the class
this.graphics.clear();
```

Comment: Nae bother, glad it helped!